# image serving with google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I add an image in a datastore as a blobproperty. I don't want to user BlobStore because I don't know if I will stay on GAE in the future. The problem is that I cannot see the image. I see the "broken icon" instead.

Here is how I store the image

```
app = Applications()
image = str(self.request.get("image"))
app.img = db.Blob(image)
app.put()
```

the img is a db.BlobProperty()

Here is the image serving class I made:

```
class ApplicationImageHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        sURL = self.request.url.split("/")
        app = Applications.get_by_id(long(sURL[-1]))
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
        self.response.out.write(app.img)
```

Here is the page when I call it: `http://localhost:9082/applications/6310509548666880`

And here is how I call it: `<img src="/images/{{app.key().id()}}">`

The "app" is the whole entity from the database when I render it in the html.

If I copy the link and paste it in the browser, then I have the same "broken icon".

**Edit:** I just see on the log that I have a code 200 on image. So, I am more confuse now :P

```
INFO     2013-06-01 15:18:27,650 server.py:585] default: "GET /images/4762397176758272 HTTP/1.1" 200 10
```

And here is the part of the html form I use to get the image:

```
<span>
  <input type="file" name="image">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try requesting the image directly from your browser and see if it looks right:

```
http://localhost:9082/images/4762397176758272
```

If that doesn't work, then the problem is either in your ApplicationImageHandler, assuming that server.py:585 is in your get() method, or it's in the image upload process.  Are you sure that it's an image/jpeg?  Did you include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form?

Also, are you using Django or Jinja templates?  If you are using Django, then `{{app.key().id()}}` is incorrect -- you should use `{{app.key.id}}` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Jinja and I have already test the link directly to my browser. The same "broken" icon. The problem was on the html form. I include the enctype="multipart/form-data" and now works great. Thanks